LCD TV (Littelfuse?) component marked BK 2CIJ8
I am an amateur in electronic component repair and I have started to repair my old LCD TV. The problem is that I found a component that I believe is the source of the problem, but I cannot identify it or find its specifications on the internet. Do you have any idea what this component might be? (I think it could be a Littelfuse component.)

The component is marked with a logo and what appears to be "BK 2CIJ8".

That is most likely a SMA6L14A from Littlefuse, datasheet

2Cij8 is the date code.


It is a TVS diode. It is a passive device and typically does nothing. It usually fails Open Circuit. If it fails to open, it will not cause any problems. You can remove it from the circuit, and it will function normally.
In the unlikely event it fails shorted, it will short out whatever it is terminated to, like an input/output port or power rails.
It can only cause you a problem if it fails shorted. A TVS device will trip at a specified voltage, 14 volts for this one, and hold a short circuit until the transient clears or blows itself up trying.  A quick ohmmeter check will tell you.
